# Will using the C# assignment make a new copy of the object or make it an alias?

Tags: c#

I have an object of `ClassA` called `obj`.

What is the difference between

```
ClassA obj2 = obj;
```

vs

```
ClassA obj2 = new ClassA(obj);
```

Is my understanding correct that the first one makes an alias for `obj` whereas the second one makes an actual copy of `obj`?

Comment: yes, what  you call an alias is typically called a reference.

Comment: It would be good to see the Definition of `ClassA`

Comment: Assume ClassA is a non-complicated, has just an integer data member.

Comment: C# has no built-in way to reliably create a copy of an object.  Very much design, many C++ programmers died trying to implement the rule-of-three and the rule-of-five.  It is code you have to write explicitly, be sure to not use the ICloneable interface.  A custom constructor is good, a virtual DeepClone() method is good.  Emphasis on "deep", the nasty detail that gets everybody in trouble.

Comment: appending a new question to your question will be confusing and may make your answers received invalid... best to start with a new fresh question and delete the UPDATE you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say ClassA is:

```
class ClassA
    {
        public int a;

        public ClassA()
        {

        }

        public ClassA(ClassA obj)
        {
            this.a = obj.a;
        }
    }
```

It's best if you write few lines of code to verify what would happen. E.g.

```
        ClassA obj2 = obj;
        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(obj, obj2)); // true
        obj2.a = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.a); // also 5


        ClassA obj3 = new ClassA(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(obj, obj3)); // false
        obj3.a = 15;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.a); // still 5
```

In such scenarios running small code always helps. Assigning obj2 to be equal to obj simply copies the reference found on the stack to the heap object. From that point on, you have two variables on the stack that point to the very same heap object. Modifications on one would be reflected regardless of which pointer you use to get the heap object.

In the second scenario, you have what is called Copy Constructor. It initializes a new chunk in the heap. It is new piece of memory and separate to the original object. Also the reference equals would return false, as the stack variable points to another location in the memory.

Run [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WrYaIH) code and verify for yourself.

Comment: Good info and Nice link to practice on.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example, ClassA obj2 = obj, essentially sets a new object obj2 to an existing object, hopefully of type ClassA, such that if obj is already defined, obj2 becomes equal to it in reference, but not in value.

The second example is an example of instantiation, and will use the initializer or overload method with 1 argument, if there were multiple overload methods, passing in obj as the argument for the overload method (meaning that ClassA would need to have an overload method that accepts and object of the type obj is as an argument).

Answer (score 1):

Its not really making an alias (at least by most definitions of that word).

```
ClassA obj2 = obj;
obj2 = obj3;
obj2.Something = "New Value"
```

does **not** change `obj.Something`. What the assignment *does* do for reference types is assign the reference (which can be helpful to think of as a pointer; though they aren't exactly the same).

```
ClassA obj2 = obj;
obj2.Something = "New Value"
//obj.Something is "New Value"!
```

For value types it makes a copy:

```
int test = 0;
int test2 = test; //test2 is 0
test = 1;
// test is still 0!
```

Creating a new instance of an object via instantiation of course will not have any relation to other instances of that object (aside from `static` members)

What `ClassA obj2 = new ClassA(obj);` will do depends on the definition of that constructor of `ClassA` but you'll definitely be getting a new `ClassA` object out of it.

Comment: sorry, I should have meant reference.